# Sum of series $\frac {4}{10}+\frac {4\cdot7}{10\cdot20}+ \frac {4\cdot7\cdot10}{10\cdot20\cdot30}+\cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the sum of the series

$$\frac {4}{10}+\frac {4\cdot7}{10\cdot20}+ \frac {4\cdot7\cdot10}{10\cdot20\cdot30}+\cdots?$$

I know how to check if a series is convergent or not.Is there any technique to find out the sum of a series like this where each term increases by a pattern?

Comment: In your title, it seems you have base ten numbers. In the body of the question, I would guess 4.7.10 means multiply, giving 280. Anyway, typesetting needs considerable work

Comment: Please check it now.

Comment: better, and now consistent

Comment: Easy to see sum lies between 3/7 and 2/3. Can't find value

Comment: @Manthanein No, it *isn't*.  Note the difference in the denominator.  This requires extra care is the linked answer.  Compare and contrast my solution with the one in another post, especially in terms of the number of lines of the solution.

Comment: @GNU Supporter The OP might get many different ideas from that question. Moreover he/she might intend to try on his/her own to solve the problem instead of just opening a thread on account of just the difference in the denominator. Trying on his/her own might increase the critical thinking skill too.  So I flagged I as duplicate. If it doesn't fit in the norms of duplicate I will certainly try to unflag it.

Comment: type **sum[product[(1+3k)/(10k), {k,1,n}],{n,1,infinity}]** into Wolfram alpha

Answer (score 5):

My solution is adapted from [another similar solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1653333/290189).

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{4\cdot7\cdot\cdots\cdot(3n+1)}{n!10^n}
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\frac43\cdot\frac73\cdot\cdots\cdot\frac{3n+1}3}{n!\left(10/3\right)^n}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\binom{\frac{3n+1}{3}}{n}\left(\frac{3}{10}\right)^n\\
&=\left[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\binom{\frac{3n+1}{3}}{n}x^n\right]_{x=3/10}\\
&=\left[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\binom{-\frac{4}{3}}{n}(-x)^{n}\right]_{x=3/10}\\
&=\left[ \left(\left(1-x\right)^{-4/3}-1\right) \right]_{x=3/10}\\
&=\sqrt[3]{\left(\frac{10}{7}\right)^4}-1
\end{align}

Comment: How you get -4/3 in binomial coefficient? Thank

Comment: @KingTut Short answer: copied from the linked solution.  Long answer: write it out
$$\binom{\frac{3n+1}{3}}n = \frac{\frac43\cdot\frac73\cdot\cdots\cdot\frac{3n+1}3}{n!} = \frac{\left(-\frac43\right)\cdot\left(-\frac73\right)\cdot\cdots\cdot\left(-\frac{3n+1}3\right)}{n!} (-1)^n=\binom{-\frac{4}{3}}n(-1)^n $$

Comment: I get it many thank